# How show uploaded file in vue-filpond

Tags: laravel, vue.js, filepond

i have file pond in my vue template

```
<file-pond
    name="file"
    ref="pond"
    label-idle="click to upload..."
    allowMultiple="true"
    :server="uploadSrv"
    :files="documents"
/>
```

This is a form, send this form using Laravel and validate other fields, if failed, i redirect back to this form with old value. One of this old value is added documents list.

User can add files and i see green bar with info about uploaded files. But when i click submit the form and back, cause of error i dont know how to show all uploaded files. Access to this files i have by this.old.documents

```
export default {
    props: ['old', 'errors',],
    data() {
        return {
            documents: [],      
            uploadSrv: {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
                },
                process: {
                    url: '/file/process',
                    onload: (response, data) => { return response },
                 },
            };
        },
        methods: {
          
        },
        components: {
            FilePond,
        },
        mounted() {
            if (this.old?.documents !== undefined) {
                for (var i = 0, len = Object.values(this.old.documents).length; i < len; i++) {
                    this.documents.push({
                        source: Object.values(this.old.documents)[i].url,
                        options: {
                            type: 'local'
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not using file preview, just wanna see files list
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it, i tried to do complicated but way is so simple, just need in controller get documents from database and make array

```
$abc = Files::where('token', 'gj2trq81hxf177ukl3cs61y7y72uhki5h')->get();
        foreach($abc as $f) {
            $arr[] = [
                'source' => 'https://some_image.jpg',
                'options' => [
                    'type' => 'limbo'
                ]
            ];
        }
```

`limbo` is very important, thats mean your files will be on the list without upload again, if u use `local` your files will upload again by filepond so u can have double files.